# Algebraic simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have never learned this in school, I only learned algebra when you have $x$ and numbers, in equations, like this:

$$2x = 5(-2 + 5x)^2$$

I can solve that, but I cannot solve this one:

$$-3(7 -2x)^2 -5(1 + x)^2$$

How can I solve this one?

On the book, answer is: $$-17x^2 +74x -152$$

Comment: the strategy to simplify both expressions (although the first one is an equation, while the second is not) is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression, unlike the first equation, is not an equation.

It can be simplified by *expanding* the expression:

$$-3(7 -2x)^2 -5(1 + x)^2 = -3(49 - 28x + 4x^2) - 5(1 + 2x + x^2) = \cdots$$

Can you take it from here? Just multiply each expression in parentheses by the factors $-3$, $-5$, respectively, $$-3(49+4x^2-28x) - 5(1+x^2+2x) = -147 -12x^2 + 84x - 5 - 5x^2 - 10x$$ and now combine like terms. You'll arrive at $$-17x^2 + 74x - 152$$ which cannot be further simplified.

Comment: Needs more to go with green :-) +1

Answer (score 0):

Let us do it. We have

$$-3(7 -2x)^2 -5(1 + x)^2=-3(7 -2x)(7-2x) -5(1 + x)(1+x)=
-3(49-28x+4x^2)-5(1+x^2+2x)=-147+84x-12x^2-5-5x^2-10x=-152+74x-17x^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is just to simplify the given polynomial
$$-3(7 -2x)^2 -5(1 + x)^2.$$
This can be done using the identity $(a+b)^2 = a^2+b^2+2ab$. What you get is
$$ -3(49+4x^2-28x) - 5(1+x^2+2x) = -147 -12x^2 + 84x - 5 - 5x^2 - 10x $$

which is in turn equal to the result you posted.

PS: This is not linear algebra! The squared terms are not linear.

Comment: You've made an error in your expansion: $-3 (-28x) = 84x$.